# Generate unique id for user when they will register in Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a login-registration system with PHP mysql and HTML. I want that, when user will register with his email and password, an unique ID will generate into database only for him. Example: when a user register an unique number auto create like 1, 2, 3, 4... I want an unique ID of 5 digits instead of 1, 2, 3 auto increment number.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not working for me. can you please give me a screenshot of the column. how to make the table for auto generate the unique number. It always showing me 1, 2, 3....

Answer (score 1):

Make your `id` (primary) column [auto-increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Also, add a record with id `10000` either manually or with code.

Next record added will have id `10001`.

This solves your question.

Comment: I am using mysql database directly. I don't want to use code right now.

Comment: This solution will work for you in this case also. Add a user with id `10000` or edit existing id with 5 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

```
  ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;
```

Comment: I am using mysql database directly. I don't want to use code right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `auto increment` value when you create table.

Fist make that field `primary key` and assign `auto increment` value to your desire number.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (
  id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  .........
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I am using mysql database directly. I don't want to use code right now.

Comment: I've recently realized that this, if used in a cookie, presents a security threat. One user can log in, then edit their cookie to the next number up (or a random number) and then be recognized by the site as that user. I'm going to add a column for a unique id and then generate a random id for each user to use as the cookie reference.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need to do this with your phpmyadmin UI. So go to phpmyadmin and follow the steps below.
(If you have already selected autoincrement field start from step 4).
 
1. In "Structure" tab of your table 
 2. Click on edit on column you want auto_increment 
 3. under "Extra" tab  choose "auto_increment"  
 4. then go to "Operations" tab of your table 
 5. Look for "Table options" -> auto_increment Then type 10000

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the auto increment and use **uniqid()** function then save it in the **ID** Section.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `ZEROFILL` it will prepand required `0`'s to number so try this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_teacher` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

;)